# How to store data without using database, PHP, SQL

Tags: jquery, spring, web, jakarta-ee

I want to develop a web application based on a insurance company requirements where I can only use JEE,spring and jQuery technologies. The functionality should be to login, list of policies, pay premium of a policy, payment history, premium history, update ,add new policy,.

Using php and sql it can be done in no time but the restrictions is on using these two. I have to use only Jee, spring and jQuery.

Could someone please tell me how I can store data without using database and php,sql.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data as a file is an option. But that mechanism is too risky and hard to fetch large data.

Why can't you try the Firebase database?

The [Firebase Real-time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) is a cloud-hosted NoSQL database that lets you store and sync data between your users in real-time.

If you want to execute administrative tasks from a privileged server in PHP or Java, I think you should use firebase [Firebase Real-time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)

Firebase has its own RestApi, you can use it in your API

Here the [steps to install Firebase via Jquery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

Answer (score 0):

Your responsibility as a professional engineer would be to explain and convince  that storing data without any sort of proper persistence layer (DB simply put) is a very bad practice.

You could go with files based approach but you'll end up having to solve so many problems that are already solved by any DB - it's simply ain't worth it. I personally wouldn't take a project with such requirements.